# Linq : Checking how many times the same value consecutively

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

it's my first question so if it's not quite clear , you can ask for extra information. Keep in mind that english is not my native language :).

I was wondering if it's possible to have an elegant way for next specification.
I think linq could be a possibility but i haven't got enough experience with the technology to get it to work:).

Remark this is not a homework assignment it's just a way to get an new angle to solve these kind of problems.

I've tried with the aggegrate function, maybe an action could help.

I want to keep track of:

- the max times a value occurs in an array consecutively.
- Per value it should display the maximum times the value occured consecutively

for example:

we have an array of 6 elements with elements either 0 or 1

```
0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 ,0 result : 3 times 0 , 2 times 1
0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 ,0 result : 2 times 0 , 3 times 1
0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 ,0 result : 1 time  0 , 2 times 1
0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 ,0 result : 2 times 0 , 2 times 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *It can only be counted if the next element is of the same value.* How can the first example be 3 times 0, if 0 only occurs two times consecutively? Same goes for 1, it appears 1 time consequently -> (1,1), and the next one is (1,0).

Comment: first of all thanks to Dmitry for correcting the typo:) !
second : Yuval you 've shown me that i have expressed the functional requirement wrong (wich is a huge mistake :) ),the result should be as in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think *Linq* being a good way out; but a *simple method* will do:

```
// Disclamer: Dictionary can't have null key; so source must not coтtain nulls
private static Dictionary<T, int> ConsequentCount<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

  Dictionary<T, int> result = new Dictionary<T, int>();

  int count = -1;
  T last = default(T);

  foreach (T item in source) {
    count = count < 0 || !object.Equals(last, item) ? 1 : count + 1;
    last = item;

    int v;

    if (!result.TryGetValue(last, out v))
      result.Add(last, count);
    else if (v < count)
      result[item] = count;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Tests:

```
  int[][] source = new int[][] { 
    new[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
    new[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
    new[] { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
    new[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 }, };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, source
    .Select(array => $"{string.Join(" , ", array)} result : " + 
                         string.Join(", ", 
        ConsequentCount(array)
          .OrderBy(pair => pair.Key)
          .Select(pair => $"{pair.Value} times {pair.Key}"))));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 result : 3 times 0, 2 times 1
0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 result : 2 times 0, 3 times 1
0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 result : 1 times 0, 2 times 1
0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 result : 2 times 0, 2 times 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lazy inefficient way (seems like linear complexity to me):

```
int[] arr = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 };

string str = string.Concat(arr);              // "000110"
int max0 = str.Split('1').Max(s => s.Length); // 3
int max1 = str.Split('0').Max(s => s.Length); // 2
```

---

and here is the efficient O(n) version:

```
int[] arr = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 };

int i1 = 0, i = 1;
int[] max = { 0, 0 };

for (; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] != arr[i1])
    {
        if (i - i1 > max[arr[i1]]) max[arr[i1]] = i - i1; 
        i1 = i;
    }
}
if (i - i1 > max[arr[i1]]) max[arr[i1]] = i - i1;

Debug.Print(max[0] + "," + max[1]); // "3,2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own method for groupping by consecutive

```
    public static class Extension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> list)
        {
            var group = new List<int>();
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                if (group.Count == 0 || i - group[group.Count - 1] == 0)
                    group.Add(i);
                else
                {
                    yield return group;
                    group = new List<int> {i};
                }
            }
            yield return group;
        }
    }
```

And then use it like that:

```
var groups = new[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 }.GroupConsecutive();
var maxGroupped = groups.GroupBy(i => i.First()).Select(i => new
{
       i.Key,
       Count = i.Max(j => j.Count())
});
foreach (var g in maxGroupped)
       Console.WriteLine(g.Count + " times " + g.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq will be a bit ugly, but it is possible though, your choice of `Aggregate` is the way to go, but it won't be a one liner in any case,

Something like this will work,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 };
    var result = list.Aggregate(new
                                {
                                    Last = (int?)null,
                                    Counts = new Dictionary<int, int>(),
                                    Max = new Dictionary<int, int>()
                                }, (context, current) =>

                                {
                                    int count;
                                    if (!context.Counts.TryGetValue(current, out count))
                                        count = 1;

                                    if (context.Last == current)
                                        count += 1;

                                    int lastMax;
                                    context.Max.TryGetValue(current, out lastMax);
                                    context.Max[current] = Math.Max(lastMax, count);

                                    if (context.Last != current)
                                        count = 1;


                                    context.Counts[current] = count;

                                    return new { Last = (int?)current,  context.Counts, context.Max };
                                });

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list) + "  Result: ");
    var output = string.Join(",  ", result.Max.Select(x => string.Format("{0} times {1}", x.Value, x.Key)));
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, performance wise Linq might not be the right tool for the job.

My linq only version would be:

```
from array in arrayOfArrays
let result = new { 
    Zeroes = array.TakeWhile(x => x == 0).Count(), 
    Ones = array.SkipWhile(x => x == 0).TakeWhile(x => x == 1).Count()
}
select $"{String.Join(", ", array)} result : {result.Zeroes} times 0, {result.Ones} times 1"
```

I'm not sure if Linq2Objects will be smart here to optimize the query internally. We ARE within the query iterating mutliple times over the array. So like i said in advance there may be a performance hit if you execute this over a lot of arrays. If anyone would care to check performance of this in regards to other non linq solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to everyone who put the time and effort in answering the question.

I've choosen Dmitry Bychenko as a valid answer , he was the first to provide an answer , and it was an elegant answer.

Matthew diserves also credit because he has shown me how the aggregate function works with conditionals.

last but not least the answer of victor was the simplest one. I did enhance it to work with generics .

```
 void Main()
    {
            var groups = new[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,30,1,1,1,1,1 , 22, 22, 15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0 }.GroupConsecutive();

    groups.Dump();
            var maxGroupped = groups.GroupBy(i => i.First()).Select(i => new
            {
                   i.Key,
                   Count = i.Max(j => j.Count())
            });

    foreach (var g in maxGroupped)
           Console.WriteLine(g.Count + " times " + g.Key);
    }

     public static class Extension
        {

            public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupConsecutive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) 
            {
                var group = new List<T>();
                foreach (var value in list)
                {
                    if (group.Count == 0 || value.Equals(group[group.Count-1])) 
                        group.Add(value);
                    else
                    {
                        yield return group;
                        group = new List<T> {value};
                    }
                }
                yield return group;
            }
```